# Quiz result posting without permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I made a app on Facebook which works like a little quiz.
You just have to answer 4 questions and after it you get one of three possible results.

Now I want a button where people can PUBLISH their result, but I don't want to have one of those popups at the start of the application where people have to agree something.

I don't want to automaticly post something on user walls - just if they hit the button they get another Facebook Popup where they can decide if they wanna post the template give on their own wall ...

is it possible ? and if it is ... how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the Feed Dialog. Have a look at the Direct URL Example on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and attach the link to a button in your app.

Comment: that helped only a bit - since now I am getting a API Error-Code 191 all the time ... whatever I change in my settings :/ - 
look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308232/facebook-api-error-code-191-feed