# Facebook Feed Dialog Returns API Error Code: 191

Tags: facebook, api, feed, error-code

In my Facebook App I'll always get the following error :

> An error occurred. Please try again later.
>   API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

I just want to feed a post via button my code is

```
  function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://mydomain.com/',
      picture: 'https://mydomain.com/img/feed.png',
      name: 'BLABLADialog',
      caption: 'UeberschriftBLABLA',
      description: 'DescriptionBLABLA',
      show_error: true
    };
    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }
    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

my Canvas-URL is "http://mydomain.com/"
my Secure Canvas-URL is "https://mydomain.com/"
my Tab-URL is "https://mydomain.com/tab.php"
my Secure Tab-URL is "https://mydomain.com/tab.php"
my Website with Facebook Login SITE URL is "https://mydomain.com/"

so what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please provide a link to a sample URL where you have this code

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a redirect_uri in your `var obj` array. On the [Feed Dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), `redirect_uri` is specified as:

> The URL to redirect to after the user clicks a button on the dialog. **Required**, but automatically specified by most SDKs.

So it must be specified, and it must a URL that falls under the Site URL of your app.

Comment: added redirect_uri : 'content.bet90arena.com', to my script but still getting' the same error :(

Comment: Do you have content.bet90arena.com as one of your App Domains as well as your Site URL?

Comment: it is one of my app domains and my SITE URL ? where can I specify that ? just found that Website with Facebook Login SITE URL ...

Comment: App Domains is under Settings -> Basic -> Basic info -> App Domains (above Hosting URL and below Contact Email).

Comment: yea "APP domains" is already right configured ... but where can I find this "SITE URL" ?

Comment: As you mentioned it is under the Website with Facebook Login options

Comment: well then I have everything right ... but somehow I still get this API Error :/

Comment: http://i1145.photobucket.com/albums/o501/King_Coatie/notworking.gif

please check this